# How to redirect a module button to a specific external Url

Tags: views, forms

I'm trying to make a button type to redirect in an external Url and I don't know how to make it. 
I already make the simple Form and I need help for make this function.
I'm using Drupal 8
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already try it and I got this error :"Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse "

Comment: @JohnJameson – You need to add all this info to your question then. The exact code you used, where you used it, the error you got, the link to the other question.